# azure devops pull request templates: separate template per folder?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

I have a repo with a couple different top level folders and would like to know if there's a way to create separate pull request templates for these folders.

For instance, let's say I have:

```
<repo>
    server
    client
    shared
```

I want separate pull request templates for each of the categories because there are distinctly different things to ask for in each.

Is it possible to have pull request templates based on paths rather than branches?

Answer (score -2):

Currently, it's not possible to have pull request templates based on paths rather than branches.

The pull request is the collaborative process that lets the rest of the team discuss changes in a branch and agree to merge them once everyone approves. You may try to create branches for each function. For example, create 3 branches from master, branch1 focus on "server" folder, branch2 focus on "client" folder, branch3 focus on "shared" folder. Then create pull requests for each branch.

Comment: We also would like to be able to load in PR templates based on the paths the changes exist under. We work in a large MonoRepo so a generic PR template is not possible. Changing our branching strategy such that each component operates in it's own branch is not a solution.

Comment: The long-lived branching idea goes against good CI practices, which would be harmful and not at all a good trade for multiple templates.